# Custom PDF invoice in Admin view in Prestashop 1.7.8.7

Tags: backend, prestashop-1.7

i had a module **for export a custom PDF file already maked**.
When i click PDF button for generate invoice in order list, the module created an overide for dowload my custom PDF instead of original generated by prestashop.
Before with 1.7.5.X version it works but now it works only for front view , in back-end admin the override like before not work. what i need to change ?
**i suspected that the AdminPdfController no loger used in new version.**

the override it's on
**/override/controllers/admin/AdminPdfController.php**

the code that right now not works and with old version worked is :

```
    <?php
class AdminPdfController extends AdminPdfControllerCore {
    /*
    * module: aggiornamentias400
    * date: 2018-09-13 18:49:07
    * version: 1.0.0
    */
  public function generateInvoicePDFByIdOrder($id_order)
    {
        $order = new Order((int)$id_order);
        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($order)) {
            die($this->trans('The order cannot be found within your database.', array(), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Notification'));
        }
        $reference = $order->reference;
        $file = @glob(_PS_ROOT_DIR_."/../fatture/*_$reference*.PDF");
        $fattura = file_get_contents($file[0]);
        if ($fattura){
        $order_invoice_list = $order->getInvoicesCollection();
        Hook::exec('actionPDFInvoiceRender', array('order_invoice_list' => $order_invoice_list));
        $this->generatePDF($order_invoice_list, PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE, $reference);
        } else {die($this->trans('la Fattura AS400 non è ancora disponibile', array(), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Notification'));}
    }
    /*
    * module: aggiornamentias400
    * date: 2018-09-13 18:49:07
    * version: 1.0.0
    */
     public function generatePDF($object, $template, $reference='')
    {
        
        if ($template == PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE) {
        if (!empty($reference)) {
        $file = @glob(_PS_ROOT_DIR_."/../fatture/*_$reference*.PDF");
        $data = file_get_contents($file[0]);
        header("Content-type:application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"Fattura_$reference.pdf\"");
        echo $data;
        }else {
        $pdf = new PDF($object, $template, Context::getContext()->smarty);
        $pdf->render();
         }
        }
    }
        /*
    * module: aggiornamentias400
    * date: 2018-09-13 18:49:07
    * version: 1.0.0
    */

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In new versions you have 2 ways for this purpose:

1. Use "actionPDFInvoiceRender" hook to make your changes if it is possible
2. Decorate "prestashop.adapter.pdf.order_invoice_pdf_generator" symfony service in your module